# How can I run Parsec streaming service on a GCP instance without a GPU? (Error Code 15000)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud, virtual-machine

I am attempting to run Android Studio on a GCP n1-standard-4 instance following this [article](https://medium.com/@rishit.dagli/set-up-a-android-development-environment-in-gcp-15ca742b63be). Everything works fine until it comes to accessing the instance. However, Chrome RDP gives poor resolution and I would prefer to use something better, which is [Parsec](https://parsecgaming.com/). Once I try to connect to the instance, I get the error 15000, 'The host encoder failed to initialize'. I do not have a GPU attached to this instance, so could this be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [Parsec documentation](https://support.parsecgaming.com/hc/en-us/articles/115002624051-Error-Codes-22006-and-15000-Unable-To-Initialize-Encoder-On-Your-Server-):

> **Error Codes - 22006 and 15000 (Unable To Initialize Encoder On Your Server)** This is an issue on the host's PC. Below are the things that
> can cause it.
>
> Check that your GPU is supported! The is the most common issue. **If
> your GPU is not supported, none of these solutions will help you**, and
> you will require a new GPU or PC to be able to host. If your GPU is
> supported, continue on below.

As you can see, you should use supported GPU with supported drivers for Parsec.

**To solve your issue** you should use [supported GPU](https://support.parsecgaming.com/hc/en-us/sections/115000675212-Hardware-Supported), also be sure that you're using [supported OS](https://support.parsecgaming.com/hc/en-us/sections/115000707272-Operating-Systems) and drivers.

In addition, have a look at the documentation [GPUs on Compute Engine](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/gpus) and [Adding or removing GPUs](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/gpus/add-gpus) if you decided to use specific GPU.